# Is there a way to implement a trait for iterators over all reference types generically?

Tags: rust

I have a trait

```
trait Foo<T> : Iterator<Item=T> {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64;
}
```

I want to implement this trait once for a type `T` (in my case `f64`) over all its reference types (`f64`, `&'a f64`, and `&'a mut f64`) since logically it doesn't matter.

I currently have

```
impl<T: Iterator<Item = f64>> Foo<f64> for T {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64 {
        // duplicated code
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Iterator<Item = &'a f64>> Foo<&'a f64> for T {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64 {
        // duplicated code
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Iterator<Item = &'a mut f64>> Foo<&'a mut f64> for T {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64 {
        // duplicated code
    }
}
```

Is there a good way to accomplish this without duplication?

Comment: I don't exactly know how to do it all in one. Without knowing exactly what you're after though, you might be able to get away with moving the duplicate code into a helper function via the use of the `Borrow` trait? [This playpen might provide a possible solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=296e500aa94741cb59af262454f5f413&backtrace=0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait for this. If you look at the implementors in the documentation page, the first three are relevant here: it means that `f64`, `&'a f64` and `&'a mut f64` all implement `Borrow<f64>`. You'll have to call the [`borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#tymethod.borrow) method on each value produced by the iterator to obtain a `&f64`.

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

impl<T> Foo<T::Item> for T
    where T: Iterator,
          T::Item: Borrow<f64>
{
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64 {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

---

By the way, it doesn't really make sense to define a type parameter on the trait and at the same time put a constraint between that type parameter and a supertrait's associated type. A type `T` can only have one implementation of `Iterator`, therefore it can only have one implementation of `Foo` as well, despite the type parameter suggesting that it could implement many different `Foo<T>` traits. Therefore, the type parameter on `Foo` is completely redundant (you can just use the supertrait's associated types instead of the type parameter). Thus the code should look more like this:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Foo: Iterator {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64;
}

impl<T> Foo for T
    where T: Iterator,
          T::Item: Borrow<f64>
{
    fn bar(&mut self) -> f64 {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to quickly test this at my C# job at work in the playpen while on my lunch break.. so I couldn't think quick enough to figure out the syntax exactly. I am glad I was on the right path somewhat though!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead you'll get to the point where you can bash out Rust code while your integration tests run. Then while the unit tests run. Then while Intellisense draws squiggles. ;-)

Comment: @Shepmaster haha - I hope so. The context switching between Rust and .NET in the middle of the day is a bit jarring; even when I have 5 minutes to context switch while my integration tests run :P